# MongooseError when using passport to authenticate user

Tags: authentication, mongoose, passport-local

Learner here and I got stuck with an error when learning and building a basic login route in JS using passport. Error is MongooseError: Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback. I'm getting this within this block of code in the .findOne() method.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(

function(username, password, done) {

User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) { //error handler catches it here

if (err) { return done(err); }

if (!user) { return done(null, false); }

if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }

return done(null, user);

});

}

));
```

I tried .then().catch() instead of using a callback in the .findOne() method itself and modified the code to following,

```
passport.use(new passportLocal(

function(username, password, done) {

User.findOne({ username: username })

.then(user =>{
if (!foundUser) { return done(null, false); }
if (!foundUser.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
return done(null, user);

})

.catch(e =>{

return done(e);

})

}));
```

This didn't work and still left scratching my head.

The login route code is as follows;

```
router.get('/login', (req, res)=>{

res.render('users/login')

});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {failureFlash: true, failureRedirect: '/login'}), async(req, res) => {

req.flash('success', 'Welcome Back.');

res.redirect('/campgrounds')

});
```

Out of ideas with my still fairly limited experience. Had a look at a few previous posts, but, they aren't related to passport authentication. Any input is hugely appreciated.